# pubsub.fire is not firing to subscriber component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have two components one is for getting input(basically a contact name) on clicking that name it should show the contact details in the Subscriber component.
I could see that for loop has some mistake as I noticed that console in for loop is not coming.

**Apex**:

```
public with sharing class searchContact {    
        @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static List<Contact> getContact(String strSearchName){    
           String searchName = '%'+strSearchName+'%';    
            return [SELECT Id, Name, Phone,Email FROM Contact where Name LIKE  :searchName];            
        }    
}
```

**Publisher**:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Search Contacts">
    <div class="slds-card slds-card_boundary slds-m-around_medium">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium slds-grid slds-gutters">
            <lightning-input label="Name"  onchange={searchContact} ></lightning-input>
            </div>
            </div>
            <template if:true={contacts}>
                <template for:each={contacts} for:item="contact">
                    <li key={contact.Id}>                        
                            <a data-position={contact.Id} onclick={handleName}>{contact.Name}</a>                      
                    </li>
                </template>
            </template>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement,track,api } from 'lwc';
import pubsub from 'c/pubsub' ; 
import getAllContact from '@salesforce/apex/searchContact.getContact'; 

const columns = [{
    label : 'Name',
    fieldName : 'Name',
    type : 'url',
    typeAttributes : {label : {fieldName : 'Name'}}},
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone', type: 'Phone' },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'Email' },
] ;
export default class SearchContactComp extends LightningElement {
    @track columns = columns;
    @track searchRecord;
    @api contacts;

        searchContact(event)
        {
            this.searchRecord = event.target.value;
            console.log(this.searchRecord);
            getAllContact({strSearchName : this.searchRecord}).then(response =>
                {
                    this.contacts = response;
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log('There is an issue in loading the account');
                })
        }
        handleName(event){
            let position = event.target.dataset.position;
            console.log(position);
            for(let i=0; i<contacts.length;i++)
            {
                console.log('For loop');
                if(this.contacts[i].Id == position)
                {
            console.log("Record Detial");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.contacts[i]));
            pubsub.fire('showdetails',this.contacts[i]);
            console.log("Fired");
            }
        }
        }    }
```

**Subscriber**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Subscriber">
        <div class="slds-p-around_large">
          Name : {contactRecord.Name}<br/>
          Email : {contactRecord.Email}<br/>
          Phone : {contactRecord.Phone}<br/>
        </div>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
import pubsub from 'c/pubsub' ; 
import getAllContact from '@salesforce/apex/searchContact.getContact'; 
export default class SubComponent extends LightningElement {

   //COntact
    @track contactRecord={};
    
    connectedCallback(){
        pubsub.register('showdetails',this.handleEvent.bind(this));
        console.log('Subscriber');
    }

    handleEvent(payload){
        console.log('handle Event');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(payload));
        this.contactRecord=payload;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the line `for(let i=0; i<contacts.length;i++)`.. here it should be `for(let i=0; i<this.contacts.length;i++)`